# Can I use XNA 4.0 assemblies inside Visual Studio 2010 without XNA Game Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xna

I just want to use the assemblies inside my app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make this another answer since I want to share a code snippet.

If for some reason VS is hiding the XNA assemblies, you might try adding them to your project manually.

Unload the project in solution explorer, and then right click it and click Edit Project. Then under `Project/ItemGroup`, where all the `<Reference>` tags are, add the XNA references (just the ones that you need, of course):

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Your users need to install the XNA runtime, but otherwise yes, you can use the XNA assemblies in any typical (32-bit) .NET application.

Comment: So for this I just need to install XNA 4.0 framework redistributable? By this I am talking about me using it to develop in VS2010.

Comment: Yep, as far as I remember, I think you just need the runtime even for development -- though I'm not 100% certain on that.

Comment: You can try it out quite easily, just install the XNA redist on your dev machine and go to Add Reference and see if Microsoft.Xna.Framework is in there. I think you'll be missing is the Visual Studio support for Windows Phone/360 remote debugging and compiling content.

Comment: I tried exactly that but xna assemblies do not show up there, after installing the redistributable.

Comment: I could but they are in GAC. Don't think it's ok to add references manually from GAC, no?

Comment: Hmm... Well they're in the Add References .NET tab for me. I doubt this is the reason, but maybe you need XNA Game Studio installed on the dev machine. Is there a reason you're avoiding doing that?

Comment: Yeah I don't want to clutter my PC with unnecessary apps. Did you install it yourself? If that's the case, then I agree this would be it. I read that installing it makes VS see them too. But your new answer did the trick so it's enough for me.

Comment: @Joan Yeah, I did. That's weird, you'd think VS just spits out everything in the GAC indiscriminately.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too, it's really weird. They should also serve the libraries separately for people like us IMO.

Answer (score 0):

some of them yes if you install the redistributable, but you will not get the content pipeline and i think xact, thay are only part of the full install

Comment: Thanks I did this but they don't show up in the Add References dialog.

Comment: Actually they are in GAC but they are not visible in VS, not sure why.